# Kotlin binding view: How to distinguish between view variable with local variable?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin view binding for getting view reference and set data to views but I've one problem:

I have a local variable named **title**

```
val title = "any text"
```

and in the view, I've a TextView with id **title**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

so how can I distinguish between them?

Comment: You have `<bindingname>.<view id>.text` if you need the TextView text while if you need the property title then it is straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `title` as ID in the first place. Name it `titleTextView`. This yields a variable where the purpose is clear, which is good convention.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest use `as` to locally rename the `TextView`:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout_file_name>.title as lblTitle

//Usage
val title = "any text"
lblTitle.text = title
```